# Azure Search: aggregate results across multiple indexes and/or search services

Tags: indexing, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Circumstances outside my control obligate me to use multiple indexes and possibly multiple azure search services to store searchable data.

Since multiple index queries are not supported and the search results relevancy scores are relative to their indexes - how would one get results compiled from multiple search sources, order them somewhat reasonably, and support paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's required to search across multiple indexes, it's an option to build a new index that contains data from them. We will get paging and meaningful ranking.

If it's required to search from multiple Azure search services, an application needs to take all the services as data source and deal with ranking and paging itself. This is much more complicated.